# Azure pipeline throws SSL error when using System.Diagnostics to get Activity.Current.Id

Tags: .net, azure, api, ssl, azure-pipelines

I recently updated an existing .Net 5 api to get the trace id so that I could include it in responses. The api is not hosted in Azure but we use Azure devops for deployment pipelines.
This pipeline had worked for multiple deployments recently.
When I attempted to build this update the pipeline failed at the step where an agent job publishes the results of the unit tests run. It threw this error:

##[error]The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

The pipeline went back to working perfectly after I removed this line of code and the reference to System.Diagnostics:
this.traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? string.Empty;

Unfortunately, I don't know how to access the worker logs to see the inner exception. I downloaded the agent logs that don't contain any additional info that seems useful. Can anyone explain how to fix the pipeline so that I can get the trace id?

Answer (score 0):

We received the same error messages on 3/22/2022 on long established pipelines. When searching for an answer, I stumbled upon this: [Deprecating weak cryptographic standards](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/).

The failures corresponded with the planned support interruptions by Microsoft. This effort served to notify users that they need to support TLS 1.2:

[image: Microsoft planned outage times]

We're still not sure what we need to fix as the boxes that our Azure Agents are running on fully support TLS 1.2.

As far as getting a "trace id", I'm not sure. However, you can enable diagnostics on the pipeline which will provide you far more detailed logs. To do this, check the "Enable system diagnostics" checkbox in the lower left corner of the "Run pipeline" panel:

[image: Enable system diagnostics checkbox]